# flutter:: `flutter_audio_recorder, storage_path` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, dart

When I ran flutter run, I got the following error:

`flutter_audio_recorder, storage_path` use a deprecated
version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime
failures, or future build
failures, try to see if these
plugins support the Android V2
embedding. Otherwise, consider
removing them since a future
release of Flutter will remove
these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a
look at the docs for migrating the
plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

How can I solve this?
`flutter_audio_recorder' and 'storage_path` are the package names I use.

Comment: use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) instead of `storage path` and [flutter sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) for `flutter_audio_recorder`

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without changing the package?